Is it possible to use an Array of criteria for a Filter function in Google Sheets?
I have a list of items with associated point values that I want to be able to dynamically filter into a simplified form to give to others. I have a list of the key values alongside checkmarks, to make it visually evident which keys are being included in the filtered list, as below.




Keys




Checkbox
Key 1


Checkbox
Key 2


Checkbox
Key 3



I am able to get an array of values representing every key that is next to a ticked checkbox pretty easily using the filter function as follows: =FILTER({$B$3:$B},$A$3:$A=TRUE)
When only one checkbox is ticked, then feeding this output into another filter function as the criteria successfully creates the intended filtered list: =IFERROR(FILTER({'40k Army Lists'!$A$2:$A,'40k Army Lists'!$D$2:$D,'40k Army Lists'!$F$2:$F},'40k Army Lists'!$E$2:$E=FILTER({$B$3:$B},$A$3:$A=TRUE)))
Screenshot of the Filtered Table
However, if multiple keys are selected, the resulting table comes back empty:
Screenshot of Failed Filtered Table
My assumption is that the criteria being passed an array results in no matches because no cell in the criteria range matches the entire criteria array. Is there a way to make the outer filter check against each array element individually and return all rows that match any of the elements in the criteria array?
A link to a copy of the spreadsheet in question, for reference. The formula in question is in 'Army Lists'!D3.
I've tried using variations on the IF and COUNTIFS functions that I found recommended online, but none worked in context of using the output as input for a FILTER function.
I'm aware that you can give FILTER multiple criteria as multiple inputs, but I'm hoping to create a solution that is simple to expand, rather than hard coding to check each every possible entry.

Use QUERY() function instead. Try-
=QUERY('40k Army Lists'!A3:F,"select A,D,F where E matches '" & TEXTJOIN("|",1,FILTER({$B$3:$B},$A$3:$A=TRUE))&"'")



Oh that is straight up wizardry.

@MLeonard So, did it help? If it works then please consider accepting the answer (tick mark the answer).
